# how to print content of ngCMatrix class in R?

Tags: r, arules

I am generating transactional data using `as()` function. The obtained result of `as()` function has following structure:

```
Formal class 'transactions' [package "arules"] with 3 slots
  ..@ data       :Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:24375] 0 5 11 0 5 8 11 12 0 5 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:7992] 0 3 8 12 15 18 20 22 26 32 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 13 7991
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..@ itemInfo   :'data.frame': 13 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ labels: chr [1:13] "ATM" "AUTO" "CCRD" "CD" ...
  ..@ itemsetInfo:'data.frame': 7991 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ transactionID: chr [1:7991] "500026" "500075" "500129" "500256" ...
```

I want to see contents of @data field, which is an instance of ngCMatrix class. How to see it? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
> data(Groceries)
> as(Groceries, "ngCMatrix")
  169 x 9835 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"

  frankfurter               . . . . . . . . . . . . . | . . . . . . . . 
  [rest omitted]
```

A few notes:

- Don't directly access the slot data with @data. The representation might change in future releases.
- For computational efficiency, the matrix is transposed, i.e., items are rows and transactions are columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
summary(ngcmatrix)
```

will give you the itemNum and its belonging column(transpose of usual transation set in which the row represent each transation);